# How to use tags associated to API key in Resource Policy in API Gateway (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to make it so that certain APIs can only be reached by people with the correct tag (in this it is named appKey) associated to their API key. From my understanding of https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-tagging.html this should be possible. When creating the tag it also states:

```
You can tag your resources with a key-value pair. Tags are useful for tracking cost allocation among your AWS resources. They can also be used to control access to your AWS resources.
```

Which suggests it is possible but
I can't get it to work and struggling to find any documentation with examples of using tags associated to API keys. Currently my Resource Policy looks something like:

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx/*/GET/pathA/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx/*/GET/pathA/${appKey}"
        }
    ]
}
```

So the above should allow access to all APIs then restrict access to an API on pathA/* unless the 'appKey' tag associated to the API key is used in which case that one route should be allowed. The idea being we don't want people with API key A to access API key B's link and vice versa. Making the API key required only enforces it is valid API key but not which routes are when combined with path parameters.

I know I must be doing something wrong, I have also tried with ${aws:ResourceTag/appKey} and ${aws:appKey} but to no avail. I know an alternative is using a lambda but this brings additional costs and processing for something that should be possible this way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, or suggestions on other methods to achieve this.